# AIX equivalent of ieee754.h

Tags: c, serialization, include, aix, ieee-754

I wrote some C code that serializes certain values into a file that is subsequently deserialized (using custom code) in Java on another machine.

Among values I'm serializing are 64-bit double precision floating point real numbers. When I wrote the code, it was going to be compiled and run only on Linux with a `gcc` available to compile it. I used `ieee754.h` to get access to all parts of the value, as per IEEE 754 standard, and write those parts to a file. On Java end, I would simply use [`Double.longBitsToDouble(long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#longBitsToDouble%28long%29) to reassemble the value.

The problem is that I've been asked to make the code able to compile and run on AIX 5.3, using `xlc` 10.

Is there any equivalent of `ieee754.h` on AIX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of endianness issues, IEEE754 is a fixed format. There's no need for a system header to tell you what it looks like. Just do something like:

```
uint64_t rep;
double x;
memcpy(&rep, &x, sizeof rep);
```

You might want to include some code for conditionally byte-order-swapping the result if you're on a platform where you have to do that, but as far as I know, AIX is not going to be one of those.

Comment: So the internal representation of double precision floats on AIX is guaranteed to be in IEEE 754 format? I know it might sound stupid, but I wasn't sure about this, since C is notoriously bad with guarantees of that kind.

Comment: I would assume so, but you might want to check. In general, if the system's floating point format is not IEEE, converting it to IEEE may be a lossy operation, but you can use `frexp` and `ldexp` to separate out the mantissa/exponent and do it yourself that way if you like.